# How to append columns as additional rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like that currently

| Type | a_PORT | a_BENCH | a_ACTIVE | b_PORT | b_BENCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| None | 20 | 25 | 18 | 30 | 50 |

How do I add stack the columns such that I obtain this instead?

| Type | PORT | BENCH | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 25 | 18 |
| b | 30 | 50 |  |

Appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Posted a solution. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a more elegant way to do this, but this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Type': {0: 'None'}, 'a_PORT': {0: 20}, 'a_BENCH': {0: 25}, 
        'a_ACTIVE': {0: 18}, 'b_PORT': {0: 30}, 'b_BENCH': {0: 50}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
     
res = df.set_index('Type').stack()
res.index = res.index.droplevel(0).str.split('_', expand=True)

res = res.reset_index(drop=False).pivot(index='level_0', 
                                        columns='level_1', values=0)

# cosmetic
res = res.loc[:, ['PORT', 'BENCH', 'ACTIVE']].reset_index(drop=False)
res = res.rename(columns={'level_0':'Type'})
res.columns.name = None

print(res)

  Type  PORT  BENCH  ACTIVE
0    a  20.0   25.0    18.0
1    b  30.0   50.0     NaN
```

*Explanation:*

- Set `Type` as the index, and apply [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to move all column names to (Multi)Index.
- Now, use [`Index.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.droplevel.html) to drop empty level 0 (i.e. `Type`), and apply [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to get a `MultiIndex` with `('a', 'Port'), ('a', 'BENCH'), etc`.
- Reset the index again to get this `MultiIndex` back as columns (i.e. `'level_0'` and `'level_1'`). Now, apply [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).
- Finally, apply some cosmetic modifications.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# drop the Type, we don't need that when melting
df2=df.drop(columns='Type')

#melt to make the DF vertical
df2=df2.melt(var_name='Type')

#split the Type on "_", and create addl columns
df2[['Type','col']]=df2['Type'].str.split('_', expand=True)

#finally, pivot to re order
df2.pivot(index='Type', columns='col', values='value').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

```
    Type    ACTIVE  BENCH   PORT
0      a    18.0    25.0    20.0
1      b    NaN     50.0    30.0
```

Comment: Thank @AnoushiravanR for catching the duplication, I fixed the code. Regards!